# Проблема с отображением русских символов при выводе данных из бд [PHP]

Tags: php, wordpress, база-данных

Возникла проблема с отображением русских символов на сайте при выводе данных из бд.
Видел различные статьи о том, что проблема может быть в кодировке бд и/или сайта.

Кодировка бд - utf8mb4 ; таблицы - utf8mb4_general_ci

Проблема заключается в том, что сайт на Wordpress и соответственно нет файла index.html/.php
Как можно решить данную проблему в таких условиях?

Код :

```
  $host = 'localhost';
  $user = 'user'; 
  $pass = 'pass'; 
  $db_name = 'db_name';
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); 


  $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `team_id`, `name`, `description` FROM `teams`');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
 {
    echo "<span style='color: #F8F8FF';>{$result['team_id']}: {$result['name']} <br>{$result['description']}</span><br>";
  }
```

Comment: Нужно правильно настроить хостинг, если я правильно понял этот поток сознания без конкретики.

Comment: С хостингом всё в порядке